# Element ol is not allowed here (HTML)- Not sure what's going on

Tags: html, html-lists

Admittedly, I'm new to coding so I'm sure there may be many issues in my code. The errors that are showing up right now are all " Element ol is not allowed here." If someone can please help me resolve this, it would be greatly appreciated, thank you. My code is listed below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Paula's Lists</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lists.css">
    <style>
        .instagramlogo{
            position: absolute;
            width: 50px;
            left: 20px;
            top: 20px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .linkedinlogo{
            position: absolute;
            width: 50px;
            left: 100px;
            top: 20px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        .column1 {
            margin-top: 40px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            margin-left: 600px;
            width: 40%;
            padding: 10px;
            border-radius: 25px;
        }
        .column2{
            margin-top: 20px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            margin-left: 600px;
            width: 40%;
            padding: 10px;
            border-radius: 25px;
        }
        .column3{
            margin-top: 20px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            margin-left: 600px;
            width: 40%;
            padding: 10px;
            border-radius: 25px;
        }
        .column4{
            margin-top: 20px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            margin-left: 600px;
            width: 40%;
            padding: 10px;
            border-radius: 25px;
        }
        .column5{
            margin-top: 20px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            margin-left: 600px;
            width: 40%;
            padding: 10px;
            border-radius: 25px;
        }
        hr{
            position: center;
            margin-top: 10px;
            border-color: #009688;
            width: 40%;
            margin-left: 31.5%;
        }




    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="banner">
    <div class="navbar">
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/shegonnacode/"><img src="images/pngfind.com-instagram-png-22629.png" alt="Instagram logo" class="instagramlogo"></a>
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/paula-m-175737200/"><img src="images/pngfind.com-linkedin-png-533561.png" alt="Linkedin logo" class="linkedinlogo"></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="resume.html">Resume</a></li>
            <li><a href="lists.html">Lists</a></li>
            <li><a href="contacts.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <h1>Paula's Lists</h1>
    <span>Get to know me better with the following lists which showcase my perspectives on tech-related concepts!</span>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column1" style="background-color:#aaa;">
            <h3>Programming Languages I'd Like to Learn</h3>
            <ol>
                <ol type="1">
                    <li>Python</li>
                </ol>
                <ol type="a">
                    <li>Javascript</li>
                </ol>
                <ol type="A">
                    <li>C</li>
                </ol>
                <ol type="i">
                    <li>Swift</li>
                </ol>
                <ol type="I">
                    <li>PHP</li>
                </ol>
            </ol>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="column2" style="background-color:#bbb;">
            <h3>Career Aspirations</h3>
            <ul style="list-style-type:disc;">
                <li>Software Engineer</li>
            </ul>
            <ul style="list-style-type:circle;">
                <li>Video Game Developer</li>
            </ul>
            <ul style="list-style-type:square;">
                <li>Cyber Security Analyst</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="column3" style="background-color:#ccc;">
            <h3>Favorite Language so Far</h3>
            <dl>
                <dt>CSS</dt>
                <dd>CSS stands for Cascading Style Sheets</dd>
            </dl>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="column4" style="background-color:#ddd;">
            <h3>Favorite Class + Topic</h3>
            <ol>
                <li>Introduction to Web Development</li>
                <ul>
                    <li>HTML</li>
                    <li>CSS</li>
                </ul>
            </ol>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="column5" style="background-color:#ddd;">
            <h3>My Inspiration in Tech</h3>
            <ul>
                <li>Elon Musk</li>
                <ul>
                    <li>Founder and CEO of Tesla + SpaceX</li>
                </ul>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src=https://my.gblearn.com/js/loadscript.js></script>
</body>
</html>
```

As I stated, I am a noob with coding as I have just begun so I believe it may have something to do with spacing. I have tried to rearrange, but have failed miserably. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In your code you have

```
        <ol>
            <ol type="1">
                <li>Python</li>
            </ol>
            <ol type="a">
                <li>Javascript</li>
            </ol>
            <ol type="A">
                <li>C</li>
            </ol>
            <ol type="i">
                <li>Swift</li>
            </ol>
            <ol type="I">
                <li>PHP</li>
            </ol>
        </ol>
```

You have `ol` elements directly inside an `ol` element. You should have `li` elements as the direct children of `ol`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol

You could have

```html
<ol>
  <li>
     <ol type="1">
       <li>Python</li>
     </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Incorrect HTML often does work and may do what you want but it is likely to be different in different browsers and lead to problems later on.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to achieve is nesting of `<ol>` (ordered list).

A nested list or a sublist is a list within a list. The trick to marking nested lists up correctly in HTML is to recognize that the sublist is actually a child of a list item and not of a list.

1. Start by creating a list. It can be ordered or unordered:

```
    <ul>
        <li>Python</li>
        <li>JavaScript</li>
        <li>C</li>
        <li>Swift</li>
        <li>PHP</li>
    </ul>
```

2. Now add a nested list to the first list item:

```
<ul>
    <li>Python
      <ul>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>JavaScript</li>
    <li>C</li>
    <li>Swift</li>
    <li>PHP</li>
  </ul>
```

**Notice that the sublist is a child and not a sibling of an `<li>` tag.**

3. And you can keep adding levels:

```
  <ul>
    <li>Python
      <ul>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item2</li>
        <ul>
            <li>Item 2-1</li>
            <li>Item 2-2</li>
        </ul>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>JavaScript</li>
    <li>C</li>
    <li>Swift</li>
    <li>PHP</li>
  </ul>
```

This is the only correct way of nesting `<ol>`

Results:

[image: Only correct way]