# How do I get my nested <ul>s to display as a dropdown when :hover is not working?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I'm working on site navigation, and I'm trying to create a dropdown menu.  I have three list items with additional unordered lists that I would like to drop down.  However, I am having issues with the :hover pseudo-class.  If I do `nav ul:hover ul {display: block;}` then a dropdown appears, but it occurs whenever I hover over any area of the navigation bar.  However, if I code `nav li:hover ul {display: block;}` then I can't get any dropdown to appear at all.  Any advice regarding what I'm doing wrong would be much appreciated.

This is the CSS I'm currently working with:

```
nav { padding: 0;
      font-size: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      position: relative;
}

nav ul { list-style-type: none;
     margin: 0.5em;
     padding-left: 0;
     font-size: 100%;
}

nav li {border-bottom: 1px solid #002171;}

nav a { text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

nav a:hover { color: #A52F00; 
          background-color: #000000; }

nav ul ul { position: absolute;
        display: none;
        padding: 0;
            }

nav ul ul li { display: block;
           background-color: #FFFFFF;
           width: 15em;
           text-align: center;
           margin-left: 0;}

nav li:hover ul { display: block; }
```

---

I am using it on the following HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Drop 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Drop 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Drop 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Drop 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Link 3 Drop</a></li>
        </ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Link 4 Drop</a></li>
        </ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Comment: your ul's are not nested in the li's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the way you're doing this nesting is not correct (as I've previously answered here in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74282873/12826055) -> Seems like people don't understand what is `ul/ol` nesting) and not to mention that this is the only correct way:

A nested list or a sublist is a list within a list. The trick to marking nested lists up correctly in HTML is to recognize that the sublist is actually a child of a list item and not of a list.

1. Start by creating a list. It can be ordered or unordered:

```
    <ul>
        <li>Python</li>
        <li>JavaScript</li>
        <li>C</li>
        <li>Swift</li>
        <li>PHP</li>
    </ul>
```

2. Now add a nested list to the first list item:

```
<ul>
    <li>Python
      <ul>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>JavaScript</li>
    <li>C</li>
    <li>Swift</li>
    <li>PHP</li>
  </ul>
```

**Notice that the sublist is a child and not a sibling of an `<li>` tag.**

3. And you can keep adding levels:

```
  <ul>
    <li>Python
      <ul>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item2</li>
        <ul>
            <li>Item 2-1</li>
            <li>Item 2-2</li>
        </ul>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>JavaScript</li>
    <li>C</li>
    <li>Swift</li>
    <li>PHP</li>
  </ul>
```

This is the only correct way of nesting `<ol>`

Results:

[image: Only correct way]

This is however, easier to do with JavaScript and CSS, so I have wrote following code, in order to demonstrate of how this should be done (check jsfiddle link below):

https://jsfiddle.net/zroqjtfe/

**NOTE THAT IN THIS JSFIDDLE YOU ACTUALLY HAVE TO CLICK ON LINK2 IN ORDER FOR THE list items to stay shown**

[image: CHECK THIS IMAGE]

Answer (score 0):

Your li and ul aren't nested correctly.

```
<li><a></a></li>
// It should be inside the li's everything down there
<ul>
//The dropdown menu
...
</ul>
```

That should fix the problem.